# void class methods cannot be resolved for objects instantiated outside of setOnClickListener

Tags: android

I'm starting to learn how to develop Android applications and am starting by just making a simple timer for steeping tea. I have the following class `Clock`:

```
//-------------
//In Clock.java
//-------------
package greenthumbtack.teatimer;

public class Clock {
    private int min;
    private int sec;

    public Clock() {
        min = 0;
        sec = 0;
    }

    public Clock(int minutes, int seconds) {
        min = minutes;
        sec = seconds;
    }

    public final void setClock(int minutes, int seconds) {
        this.min = minutes;
        this.sec = seconds;
    }

    public String toStr() {
        return String.format("%d:%02d", min, sec);
    }

    public void tickDown() {
        this.sec -= 1;
        if (this.sec == 0 && this.min == 0) {
            this.sec = 0;
            this.min = 0;
        }
        else {
            if (this.sec < 0) {
                this.sec = 59;
                this.min -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which seems fine to me. Then in `MainActivity.java` I'm trying to do the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button blackTea = findViewById(R.id.blackTeaBtn);
        final TextView timer = findViewById(R.id.timerTxt);

        final Clock clock = new Clock(); //instantiate outside OnClickListener

        blackTea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            clock.setClock(5, 0); //setClock cannot be resolved
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new CountDownTimer(1000 * 60 * 5, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        timer.setText(clock.toStr());
                        clock.tickDown(); //still fine
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
                        toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,1000);
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(1000);

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```

But if I instantiate `clock` outside of `OnClickListener` then its methods cannot be resolved. I want to instantiate it here because I have multiple buttons that will set `clock` to a different time and think it would be better to only have one `Clock` object. I did notice that in `onTick()`, `tickDown()` is found and works fine. The only way I've found that I can set a time to `clock` is instantiating it inside `OnClickListener` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button blackTea = findViewById(R.id.blackTeaBtn);
        Button greenTea = findViewById(R.id.greenTeaBtn);
        final TextView timer = findViewById(R.id.timerTxt);

        blackTea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Clock clock = new Clock(5, 10);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new CountDownTimer(1000 * 60 * 5, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        timer.setText(clock.toStr());
                        clock.tickDown();
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
                        toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,1000);
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(1000);

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```

What am I doing wrong where I cannot create this object outside of `OnClickListener` and then access its `public void` methods outside of `onTick` for setting a different time on the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Declare your variable global outside **`onCreate()`** method

```
 public class Clock {
    private int min;
    private int sec;

    public Clock() {
        min = 0;
        sec = 0;
    }

    public Clock(int minutes, int seconds) {
        min = minutes;
        sec = seconds;
    }

    public  void setClock(int minutes, int seconds) {
        this.min = minutes;
        this.sec = seconds;
    }

    public String toStr() {
        return String.format("%d:%02d", min, sec);
    }

    public void tickDown() {
        this.sec -= 1;
        if (this.sec == 0 && this.min == 0) {
            this.sec = 0;
            this.min = 0;
        }
        else {
            if (this.sec < 0) {
                this.sec = 59;
                this.min -= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView blackTea;
    TextView timer;
    Clock clock;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        blackTea = findViewById(R.id.blackTeaBtn);
        timer = findViewById(R.id.timerTxt);

        clock = new Clock();
        blackTea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clock.setClock(5, 0);
                new CountDownTimer(1000 * 60 * 5, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                        timer.setText(clock.toStr());
                        clock.tickDown(); //still fine
                    }
                    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                    public void onFinish() {
                        ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
                        toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,1000);
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(1000);

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same problem here. It is saying `setClock` cannot be resolved still.

Comment: I'm at work now. I'll test this when I get a free moment

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button blackTea;
    TextView timer;
    Clock clock;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         blackTea = findViewById(R.id.blackTeaBtn);
         timer = findViewById(R.id.timerTxt);

         clock = new Clock(); 
        blackTea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            clock.setClock(5, 0);
                new CountDownTimer(1000 * 60 * 5, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        timer.setText(clock.toStr());
                        clock.tickDown(); //still fine
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
                        toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,1000);
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(1000);

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put this line :

```
  clock.setClock(5, 0);
```

to inside onClick() method. Like this:

```
blackTea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Clock clock = new Clock(5, 10);
                new CountDownTimer(1000 * 60 * 5, 1000) {
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                        timer.setText(clock.toStr());
                        clock.tickDown();
                    }
                    public void onFinish() {
                        ToneGenerator toneGen1 = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
                        toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,1000);
                        Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        v.vibrate(1000);

                    }
                }.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong place in code to instantiate clock object.

Just remember, you should instantiate an objects before **.setOnClickListener** method:

```
...
clock = new Clock();
clock.setClock(5, 0);
blackTea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
...
```

OR inside **OnClick** method

```
...
blackTea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   clock.setClock(5, 0);
...
```